# Do I need to bother deregistering my phone state change listener if it's tied to a service and the service terminates?

Tags: android, listener

The situation is that I have my listener constructed using an anonymous inner class, as is typical, but the way of deregistering a [PhoneStateListener][1] in Android requires me to pass the listener object to the this same function that I used to register it, but use the LISTEN_NONE flag. The problem is that I can't do this with an anonymous inner class because it's, well, anonymous. Do I have to instantiate my class with a name to be able to de-register it, or can I just ignore this problem and my listener will disappear by itself when my service terminates?

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener, int)

Comment: And if it's not too much trouble, anyone have any idea why my hyperlinked text always show up correctly in the preview but never when I publish it?

Comment: No idea, it looks like you did it right.  I can't get it to work atm either.  Maybe just a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign your anonymous class to a variable, and thus pass it in multiple places:

```
PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    // class definition;
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm a bit new to anonymous classes so I didn't realise this was possible. Cheers.